# How to detect dedicated or integrated graphics card used for WebGL?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I need to detect whether the dedicated or integrated graphics card is used within an application that uses WebGL. What is the easiest way to do this ?

Comment: Why would you need to? What do you plan to do differently based on this?

Comment: Is performance the unique difference? Why you don't try a complex calculation and take time? Something like a workbench...

Answer (score 1):

You can get the vendor's name with `getParameter(VENDOR)`. If it says NVIDIA somewhere in there, then you can assume it's not integrated (unless you're on mobile), while if it says INTEL, you can assume it is. If it says AMD, you'll have to guess a bit, since they still have both integrated and discrete cards.

But other than that, no, there is no way to tell the difference.

Comment: The plan is just to inform user.